# Golang with postgres - how to use st_makepoint function

Tags: postgresql, go, postgis

I trying to insert geometry type data into postgresql database using golang.
I trying to excute golang code like below, but occur an error...
How to fix it?

```
// dsn = (postgres://user:pass@host:port...)
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", dsn)
if err != nil {
    t.Error(err)
}

defer db.Close()

_, err = db.Exec(`insert
        into
        table_a(txt, geometry)
            values('11680108',
            ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(957539, 1945129),5179), 4326))`)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }

Occur Error:
    function st_makepoint(integer, integer) does not exist
```

- go test file

Maybe "github.com/lib/pq" library does not support function of postgis (like st_makepoint)

I don't know how to use these function in golang with postgres

Comment: Did you create the postgis extension?

Comment: If you try performing the same query using the `psql` client, does it work? That would help differentiate between "problems with your code" and "problems with postgres".

Comment: @larsks

Thank you for your comments. My postgresql have been active postgis extension. And I already tried to same as query above. And It's well done.

Comment: @박건우 Try checking if you have access to the function by looking it up in the [`information_schema.routines` view](https://postgresql.org/docs/15/interactive/infoschema-routines.html), e.g. `select * from information_schema.routines where lower(routine_name::text) = 'st_makepoint';`. If you get back `0 rows` then that means that the database, to which the Go code is connecting, doesn't have the extension enabled or the _user_ with which you are connecting to that database doesn't have access granted to the function.

Comment: the scenario suggested by @mkopriva seems the most plausible one - at least using the maintenance database `postgres` sounds suspicious. Connect with psql and try `\dx`. cheers